# Best Practice for running multiple apps using docker on VPS

Tags: docker, docker-compose, devops, vps, nginx-reverse-proxy

I want to run multiple full-stack apps(MEAN) on single VPS **using docker for multiple domains with SSL**.
I have researched a lot but couldn't find any elegant solution.

**What I have tried**

I followed this tutorial: https://egghead.io/lessons/node-js-setup-an-nginx-proxy-for-a-node-js-app-with-docker, but it is for running only one app(node.js) using Nginx proxy.

**Required Features**

1. CD/CI using git
2. Easy server migration

I'm a newbie in the docker world.
Looking for Help!!

Thanks